# Can the String.replace() method in Javascript be used to add linefeeds?

Tags: javascript

Can the String.replace() method in JavaScript be used to replace an arbitrary character with a linefeed? 
e.g.

```
newString = oldString.replace(/x/, "linefeed character (\n)").
```

Comment: Yes. You may want to check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space if it doesn't seem to be working for you.

Comment: Man you literally just did it in your question. Like really?

Comment: It is not easy because it depend how the DOM will interpret the linefeed. A solution can be to change the DOM with javascript. You can cut in two the sentence and add a <br> in the middle

Comment: @stephanec Who says the string is going into the DOM?

Comment: Yes I was suggesting that to make sense of the question. Because as @MarcoBonelli said, the answer is in the question

Comment: that doesn't work.  what I'm trying to do is pull stuff out of a <textarea> and modify it.  When I do something like val.replace(/e/g, "\n") on the textarea value, I get the literal replacement:  eee -> e"\n"e"\n"e"\n".  I can duct tape it by DIY code with '<br />' or String.fromCharCode(13), but I was looking for a solution using replace()

Comment: I've posted an answer below with a working runnable code snippet. If this isn't the behaviour you're experiencing, you'll need to provide more code. Generally, it's recommended that you provide a complete executable example demonstrating the problem. From what you've shown, it's not clear how you'd get the behaviour you seem to be describing in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/6d2rajt6/

Yes:

```
var oldString = "Test<br>secondline<br>thirdline";

var pattern = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;

var newString = oldString.replace( pattern, function replacer(match){
    var newM = '\n';
    return newM;
} );

alert(newString);
```

Comment: that doesn't work. what I'm trying to do is pull stuff out of a <textarea> and modify it. When I do something like val.replace(/e/g, "\n") on the textarea value, I get the literal replacement: eee -> e"\n"e"\n"e"\n". I can duct tape it by DIY code with '<br />' (not in a textarea) or String.fromCharCode(13), but I was looking for a solution using replace()

Comment: The code is: function replClick() {
 var re = str2regExp('/' + d.getElementById('myRegExp').value + '/' + addFlags());
 d.getElementById('rightText').value =  d.getElementById('leftText').value.replace(re, d.getElementById('replStr').value);
}  where myRegExp and replStr are text input elements, rightText and leftText are textareas.  

}

Comment: function str2regExp(s) {
// s is string of form '/pattern/flags'
 var flags = s.replace(/.*\/([gimy]*)$/, '$1');    //([gimy]*)  extracts and returns flags
 var pattern = s.replace(new RegExp('^/(.*?)/'+flags+'$'), '$1'); //(.*?) extracts stuff between slashes
 return new RegExp(pattern, flags);
}

function addFlags() {
var flags='';
 flags += (d.getElementById('gFlg').checked) ? 'g' : '';
 flags += (d.getElementById('iFlg').checked) ? 'i' : '';
 flags += (d.getElementById('mFlg').checked) ? 'm' : '';
 flags += (d.getElementById('yFlg').checked) ? 'y' : '';
return flags;
} //this part too

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. A newline characters is not considered special to the `.replace(...)` method; you can use it as the replacement value just like you'd use any other string. For example:

```js
button.onclick = function() {
  // If you omit the /g flag on your pattern, it will only affect the first match.
  textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(/NL/g, '\n');
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea">fooNLbarNLbaz</textarea><br />
<button id="button">Replace NLs with New Lines</button>
```

If you're using this as the value of a typical text node in HTML (e.g. not inside of `<textarea>` or `<pre>`), you will need to be aware of text collapsing behaviour: by default, any whitespace (including newlines) will be collapsed to a single space character. This behaviour can be controlled with [the CSS `white-space` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).